# Constraint optimization problem for any dimensionality $n>1$.

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I am going to post a particular example for the sake of clarity.

> One needs to maximize a real function
>
> $F = a_1a_2 + a_2a_3 + \cdots + a_{n -
> > 1}a_n  + a_na_1;$
>
> with active constraints
>
> $h_1 = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = 0;$
>
> $h_2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots +a_n^2 =
> > 1;$

The gradients in question

$\nabla F = (a_2+a_n,a_3+a_1, \ldots , a_{n-2}+a_n,a_{n-1}+a_1);$

$\nabla h_1 = (1, 1, \ldots ,1, 1);$

$\nabla h_2 = (2a_1,2a_2,\ldots , 2a_{n-1}, 2a_n);$

Because of [Kuhn–Tucker conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) it is reasonable to write $\nabla F$ in terms of $\nabla h_1$ and $\nabla h_1$

$$\begin{cases}
a_2+a_n = \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2a_1; \\\
a_3+a_1 = \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2a_2; \\\
a_4+a_2 = \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2a_3; \\\
\ldots \\\
a_{n-2} + a_n = \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 a_{n-1}; \\\
a_{n-1} + a_1 = \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 a_n;
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2\lambda_2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -1 \\\
-1 & 2\lambda_2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & -1 & 2\lambda_2 & -1 & \ldots &0 & 0 \\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\\
0 &0 &0 & 0 & \ldots & 2\lambda_2 & -1 \\\
-1 &0 &0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 & 2\lambda_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\\ a_2 \\\ a_3 \\\ \vdots \\\ a_{n-1} \\\ a_n
\end{pmatrix} =
- \lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\\ 1 \\\ 1 \\\ \vdots \\\ 1 \\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

By adding up all equations it follows that $\lambda_1 = 0$ so it's a matter of nullspaces.

However is this attempt fruitless? I'm getting nowhere, so at this point references to similar problems would also be appreciated.

---

A few remarks:

1. Case $n=2$ is somewhat trivial, for
   all valid combinations (there are
   two of them) $F = -1$.
2. Case $n=3$ brings up the same
   problem since for all valid
   combinations $F = -1/2$.
3. $F \le 1$ is an exact upper bound (it follows from properties of scalar multiplication and constructing silly yet valid combinations for sufficiently large $n$).

Comment: In no particular order: take the discrete Fourier transform; read the faq; ask on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The Kuhn-Tucker conditions also include the  complementary slackness conditions and the constraints. These are omitted by you.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus: Can you kindly explain your suggestion concerning the discrete Fourier transform?

Comment: @Mark: Your matrix is circulant. The DFT diagonalizes circulant matrices.

Comment: @Steve Huntsman: The DFT is applicable only to  numerical matrices. The above one is not such matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked so nicely, here we go: Let $a_k = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1}b_q \exp(2\pi i k q/n)$ (where $b_q=b_{n-q}^*$ by realness). Up to normalization factors I have dropped, $F=\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}|b_q|^2\exp(2\pi i q/n)$ and your constraints give $\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} |b_q|^2 = 1$ and $b_0=0$. So it is easy now to see that $F$ is maximum when $b_1=b_{n-1}=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. In real space, $a_k = C \cos(2\pi k/n+\phi)$.

Comment: The DFT is applicable only to numerical matrices. The above one is not such matrix

Comment: I have no idea what your objection means.

Comment:  I mean that the value of $\lambda_2$ is not known. We know only $\lambda_1 = 0$.

Comment: Why did you write $\exp(2πiq)$ in your $F$? If q is integer, this equals one

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.

Comment: Also, the DFT is applicable to any finite sequence, not necessarily numerical. (We use here the 1-dimensional transformation, so I'm not sure why you're talking about applying it to a matrix). Maybe you're thinking of the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform), which is an algorithm to implement the DFT numerically?

Comment: Is it possible to solve  problem 8 from Mathematical Trivium by V. Arnold
 "What are the numbers of the maximums, minimums, and saddle points of the function $x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+t^4$ on the surface $\{x+y+z+u+t=0,x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+t^2=1,x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+t^3=c\}$, where $c$ is a real parameter?"
 in this way? 

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way of proving (what Yoav already did), but using different notation.

Let us first write the optimization problem in matrix form. First, define
\begin{equation*}
  d =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & & \cdots &0\\\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \\\\
    \vdots &  & \ddots & \\\\
    0 & 0 & \cdots & &1\\\\
    1 & \cdots &&& 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

The optimization problem at hand is
\begin{equation*}
  \max a^Tda\quad \text{s.t.}\ a^T1 = 0, a^Ta=1.
\end{equation*}
Writing $D=(d+d^T)/2$, we see that $a^Tda = a^TDa$. So we may actually solve the problem
\begin{equation*}
  \max a^TDa\quad \text{s.t.}\ a^T1 = 0, a^Ta=1.
\end{equation*}
If we pick $a$ to be the eigenvector corresponding to the second largest eigenvalue of $D$, we see that it satisfies $a^T1=0$ and $a^Ta=1$ (the first largest does not sum to zero).
(to see the $a^T1=0$ part is where we use the DFT insight used by Yoav)

Comment: The second largest eigenvector is doubly degenerate, so you actually pick an eigenvector from a 2d space, not "the eigenvector".

Comment: yes, i know that it is not "the" :-) --- (the second largest eigenvalue occurs twice)

Comment: Is it possible to solve  problem 8 from Mathematical Trivium by V. Arnold
 "What are the numbers of the maximums, minimums, and saddle points of the function $x^4+y^4+z^4+u^4+t^4$ on the surface $\{x+y+z+u+t=0,x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+t^2=1,x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+t^3=c\}$, where $c$ is a real parameter?"
 in this way? 

Comment: @Mark: maybe, though here I think first it'll be good to see how these constraints can be combined to yield a simpler problem---the cubic constraint is the troublesome one...)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a mathematical experiment, using the DirectSearch package http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=101333 , and obtained $\max f = 0.809126470893692 $ for $a_1 = .243175515810934, a_2 = .417367431111117, a_3 = .432125841032896,$ $ a_4 = .281815795280440, a_5= 0.239770895080612e-1, a_6 = -.243248539429584,$ $ a_7 = -.417366236874912, a_8 = -.432123102835062, a_9 = -.281798611220396,$ $ a_{10} = -0.0239247832264742$ in the case $n=10$. The optimal solution is not unique.

Comment: In the case n=4 I obtain $F=0$ for $a_1=- \sqrt{ \frac{1-2a^2}{2} }, a_2=a, a_3=\sqrt{ \frac{1-2a^2}{2} }, a_4=-a$ and $a \in [-\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2]$, applying the PolynomialSystem command of Maple. 

Comment: Maple produces
 $F=0.866026654668001$ for $a_1 = .256581438083553, a_2 = .380978783536669$,
$a_3 = .403290730625114, a_4 = .317540738896204, a_5 = .146705131597625$, 
$a_6 = -0.0634388318348049, a_7 = -.256584963464397$, 
$a_8 = -.380976908754637, a_9 = -.403290979782187$,
$ a_{10} = -.317537774924634, a_{11} = -.146705878274621$, 
$a_{12} = 0.0634385149651301 $ in the case n=12.

Comment: That solution is a sine wave.  That suggests the general solution is of the form $a_i=sin(2 \pi i / n)$.

Comment: @Carl Feynman: What are the amplitude and period in your suggestion? What is the optimal value of the objective function? As far as I know it, the problem under consideration is related to one of the problems from Mathematical Trivium by V. Arnold.

Comment: The period is $n$.  I failed to correctly specify the amplitude, but Yoav Kallus kindly supplied it for us.  I was going to write up a more precise answer, but Mr Kallus beat me to it.

Comment: Whoops, I see that my comment above is incorrect; Mr Kallus didn't give the amplitude either.

Comment: The amplitude can be obtained by applying Perseval's theorem.